update bitcoin core upgrade!
I have an old version of bitcoin core wallet, i can't see my balance right now. is it safe to download the new version of bitcoin core wallet? there is no chance of losing my balance after downloading the newest version? hope to get an answer soon. Thank you
Regards
Faim
